# Running second maximum of a list

Tags: code-golf, number, array

Given a list of integers, your task is to output the second largest value in the first *k* elements, for each *k* between 2 and the length of the input list.

In other words, output the second largest value for each prefix of the input.

You can output an arbitrary value for the first element (where *k* = 1), or simply omit this value, as there isn't a second maximum for a list of 1 element. You may assume there are at least 2 elements in the input.

Shortest code wins.

### Examples

```
Input:
1 5 2 3 5 9 5 8
Output:
  1 2 3 5 5 5 8
Input:
1 1 2 2 3 3 4
Output:
  1 1 2 2 3 3
Input:
2 1 0 -1 0 1 2
Output:
  1 1 1 1 1 2
```

Comment: My English isn't the best, how is `k` determined?

Comment: @LiefdeWen Output a list containing the answer for each k.

Comment: `1` is not, strictly speaking, the *second largest value* of `1,1` (2nd example) it's the second value when sorted descending.

Comment: Maybe I'm just stupid (although I suspect I could really have the weekend started..), but I'm still not sure how this works. Could someone ELI5 the last test case to me? The first two test cases I can solve by just looping over the list, determining the current minimum of the list, and then remove that item (or easier: sort list and remove last item). It gives the correct results for the first two test cases, but is obviously wrong (and will give `-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2` for the last test case.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Remember the two largest numbers you have seen. In the last case, you start with 2 being the largest, and output nothing/whatever since it doesn't make sense at this point. Then you change to 1 and 2 at the next iteration, so you output 1. This stays the same until you reach the 2 at the end, and then you have 2 and 2 as the largest and second largest

Comment: Does it make any sense at all to add an excel-based answer to this, if it relies on the input being entered one value per cell in a column and returns the output one value per cell in an adjacent column?

Comment: @Adam I guess it makes some sense. But I'm not exactly sure how to score such submissions. Maybe you could find some information on the meta.

Comment: @jimmy23013 I found two relevant threads on meta, one of which was closed as a duplicate of the other (although the answers were fairly different: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10199/what-mouse-interactions-are-allowed-by-default-as-part-of-input-output AND https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/how-should-we-handle-excel-answers-with-drag-down-formulas )  One says yes, the other says no.  My answer isn't all that exciting anyways, so I will skip it.

Comment: @Adam There are many Excel answers on this site. It's only the scoring part that I'm not sure of. I don't think anyone had the opinion that such answers shouldn't be posted. And at least the answer could be compared with other Excel answers, like the cases of Minecraft and Piet.

Comment: This could also make an interesting `restricted-complexity` challenge.

Comment: @xigoi For such a simple problem, theoretically, compilers and interpreters could automatically optimize O(n^2) answers into O(n). Most implementations don't do that, and doing that could be quite challenging itself. But it's like free points (or penalty) for the golfers because of the language creator's hidden work (or lack of it) that isn't really related to how elegant the golfed code appears to be, which I suppose is not a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
ηεà\à
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3PZzWw8viDm84P//aEMdBVMdBSMdBWMwwxJMWsQCAA)

Returns `[]` (arbitrary value) for first.

Comment: `η¦ε{¨θ` should work for 6 bytes

Comment: @Adnan Of course >_< found a better way anyways though...

Comment: Interesting... `Z©KZ®‚¹sÃ` was what I was thinkinh, didn't know `à` was even a thing!

Comment: [Found another 5-byte alternative](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138540/59487). I used `Áθ` instead.

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

Saved a byte or two thanks to @Zgarb

```
mȯ→hOtḣ
```

Returns `0` for the first "second maximum"

#### Explaination

```
         -- implicit input, e.g          [1,5,3,6]
      ḣ  -- prefixes                     [[],[1],[1,5],[1,5,3],[1,5,3,6]]
     t   -- remove the first element     [[1],[1,5],[1,5,3],[1,5,3,6]]
mȯ       -- map the composition of 3 functions
    O    --   sort                       [[1],[1,5],[1,3,5],[1,3,5,6]]
   h     --   drop the last element      [[],[1],[1,3],[1,3,5]
  →      --   return the last element    [0,1,3,5]
         -- implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fE@kdtkzL8Sx7uWPz///9oQx1THSMdYyBpCcQWsQA)

Comment: You could map `→hO` instead and save a byte.

Comment: I suppose that the Husk command "```ḣ```" (prefixes) must have subtly changed since this was originally posted, as this answer seems to work with only [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X/uifWP2iZl@D/csfj////R0YY6pjrGOmaxOmCWEZBtqmMJxBZgEUOgCEjMWMcEyDcC8g10dEEEUCI2FgA) now...

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
lambda x:[sorted(x[:i])[-2]for i in range(2,1+len(x))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBDsIgEEX3noJdIU4ToZooiSehLDAFJcGhQRZ4ehxczM//72X2b31lVD3c157c@7E51rT55FL9xpvR0QozKxtyYZFFZMXh03MF8pg88iaE7cOl4YyRcAEFC@WN7mqBiCQy2AJn2vQJJ5hHkLBWH9heIlaWYFpxgsCT@Lfefw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
poil
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FksK8jNzlhQnJRdDBRbcNIo21DHVMdIxBpKWQGwRywUUMQSKgMSMdUyAfCMg30BHF0QAJWIhWgE)

```
p     Prefix
 o    Sort
  i   Init (remove the last element)
   l  Last
```

Accidentally, [poil means hair in French](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poil).

Comment: I've been waiting so long for one of these golf langs to spell an actual word!

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>58</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

Appends `undefined` for ***k = 1***.

```js
a=>a.map(e=>(b=[e,...b]).sort((a,b)=>b-a)[1],b=[])
```

#### Test cases

*NB: This snippet uses `JSON.stringify()` for readability, which -- as a side effect -- converts `undefined` to `null`.*

```js
let f =

a=>a.map(e=>(b=[e,...b]).sort((a,b)=>b-a)[1],b=[])

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 9, 5, 8]))) // 1 2 3 5 5 5 8
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])))    // 1 1 2 2 3 3
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2])))   // 1 1 1 1 1 2
```

Comment: I think `a=>a.map(e=>(b=[e,...b]).sort((a,b)=>b-a)[1],b=[])` is only 50.

Comment: @Neil Nice. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 45 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l[1:]and f(l[:-1])+[sorted(l)[-2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIccqJ9rQKjYxL0UhTSMn2krXMFZTO7o4v6gkNUUjRzNa1yg29n9BUWZeCVA@2lDHVMdIxxhIWgKxRawmF5KUIVAKJGmsY4IsYQSUMNDRBRFAFbGa/wE)

The right side of the code is self-explanatory. However, what do we put to the left of the `and`? Because we are concatenating parts of a list recursively, we need the left side to be truthy if `l` has 2 or more elements, and an empty list otherwise. `l[1:]` satisfies this criterion nicely.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ḣJṢ€Ṗ€Ṫ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjsVeD3cuetS05uHOaWByFZD8//9/tKGOgqmOgpGOgjGYYQkmLWIB)

The first value will be 0, always, and the following numbers will be the second maximums of each prefix.

### Explanation

```
ḣJṢ€Ṗ€Ṫ€  Input: array A
 J        Enumerate indices, [1, 2, ..., len(A)]
ḣ         Head, get that many values from the start for each, forms the prefixes
  Ṣ€      Sort each
    Ṗ€    Pop each, removes the maximum
      Ṫ€  Tail each
```

Comment: @Challenger5 I don't believe that works

Comment: @Challenger5 That doesn't work...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh, ok.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 8 bytes

```
m@Sd_2._
```

**[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%40Sd_2._&input=%5B1%2C5%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C9%2C5%2C8%5D&debug=0)** or **[Try the Test Suite!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%40Sd_2._&input=%5B1%2C+5%2C+2%2C+3%2C+5%2C+9%2C+5%2C+8%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C5%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C9%2C5%2C8%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+4%5D%0A%5B2%2C+1%2C+0%2C+-1%2C+0%2C+1%2C+2%5D&debug=0)**

---

## How?

This outputs the first element of the list as the first value in the list, as per the spec *You can output an arbitrary value for the first element*.

```
m@Sd_2._   - Full program with implicit input.

m     ._Q  - Map over the prefixes of the input with a variable d.
  Sd       - Sorts the current prefix.
 @         - Gets the element...
    _2       - At index - 2 (the second highest).
           - Print implicitly.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>87</s> 86 bytes

```java
a->{int x,y=x=1<<-1;for(int c:a){if((c>x?x=c:c)>y){x=y;y=c;}System.out.print(x+" ");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9Nb4MwDIbv@RVWT0GDaHSbtJWPHXbeqceqhyyFKgwSlBgEQvx2Fihbt86K4sTvY@t1wVse6DpTxelzklWtDULhaqxBWbK8UQKlVuxNK9tUmYkIqZuPUgoQJbcW3rlUMBACLlbBIkeXWi1PUDmZ7tFIdT4cgZuz9RwNa2BmkYY@PPmw9eFhebws97MX/aPChbqA7jzeItsFufchuKSZX5mRrA6NbDlmfywuvVIhY8wZNL/9fS8dO/lwTCGHZOJBOrgvdH6fdEkYx0EY5drME0DsuDfInFKRdq9dInbCS3tv6JI@6hMRjfveYlYx3SBzThTS7m4DGy8ax@m6S864EFmNdDZzLd/2lor@LDeS6Qs)

Comment: +1 for `int x,y=x=`. I didn't know separate declaration and assignment could be done in the same statement.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 13 bytes

```
_2&{@/:~ ::#\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WL95IrdpB36pOwcpKOYaLKzU5I18hTcFQwVTBSMEYSFoCscX//wA) The first element is always 1.

## Explanation

```
_2&{@/:~ ::#\
            \  Apply to prefixes
_2&{@/:~        Sort and take second-to-last atom
     /:~         Sort upwards
_2 {             Take second-to-last atom
         ::     If there's an error (i.e only one atom)
           #     Return the length of the list (1)
```

[The space matters.](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/coco)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Ṣ-ịƊƤ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkW6D3d3H@s6tuT/4fZHTWu8gTjy//9oLs5oQx0FUx0FIx0FYzDDEkxaxOpApAzBUhBZIDIBixuBxQ10FHQhFEgRUCIWAA)

Outputs the first value of the input as the first value in the output. This can be removed for adding [one byte](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkW6D3d3H@s6tuThjq7/h9sfNa3xBuLI//@juTijDXUUTHUUjHQUjMEMSzBpEasDkTIES0FkgcgELG4EFjfQUdCFUCBFQIlYAA).

### How it works

```
Ṣ-ịƊƤ - Main link. Takes l on the left
    Ƥ - Generate the prefixes of l
   Ɗ  - Run the following code over each prefix:
Ṣ     -   Sort the prefix
 -ị   -   Take the -1th index.
      -     Jelly lists are 1 indexed and modular. This means that the 0th index of a list is the final element and -1 the second to last element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <sup><s>58</s></sup> 46 bytes

```scala
x=>2 to x.size map(x take _ sortBy(-_)apply 1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcyxCsIwAATQvV9xYwJRbKugQgt1E/QLREqsKURjGpogqeK3x2TW4W65x9mOKx6Gy010DkcuNYR3Ql8tGmPwzp5cod/iIK077bU7o6rR6AlV8FVdwA3wcytfAg9uiIfjd4EWdhjdbiKzlnJj1IScBjNK7ZQmPUlfJGcrVrAy9iZmTSnNfkQeRTIlW/7Zi7gv2CxVhAl8whc)

Takes a List as an argument, and returns a Vector.

-12 bytes from user.

Comment: Make that [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##bcyxCsIwAATQvV9xYwJRbKugQgt1E/QLREqsKURjGpogqeK3x2TW4W65x9mOKx6Gy010DkcuNYR3Ql8tGmPwzp5cod/iIK077bU7o6rR6AlV8FVdwA3wcytfAg9uiIfjd4EWdhjdbiKzlnJj1IScBjNK7ZQmPUlfJGcrVrAy9iZmTSnNfkQeRTIlW/7Zi7gv2CxVhAl8whc) by sorting in reverse, actually.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 32 bytes

```sh
for x;a+=($x)&&<<<${${(On)a}[2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxPy2/SKHCOlHbVkOlQlNNzcbGRqVapVrDP08zsTbaKLb2vyYXV5qCoYKpgpGCMZC0BGILsIghUAQkZqxgAuQbAfkGCrogAijxHwA)

Reverse `O`rder `n`umerically, `<<<` print the `[2]`nd element.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), 44 bytes

```
f(x)=[x[1...i].sort[i-1]fori=[2...x.length]]
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/08zdna8fty)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƒıṠṫt
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU5MiVDNCVCMSVFMSVCOSVBMCVFMSVCOSVBQnQmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xJTJDJTIwNSUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAzJTJDJTIwNSUyQyUyMDklMkMlMjA1JTJDJTIwOCZmbGFncz1l)

Uses `[]` as the (arbitrary) first value.

##### Explanation

```python
ƒıṠṫt  # Implicit input
ƒ      # Prefixes of the input
 ı     # Map over this list:
  Ṡ    #  Sort this list
   ṫt  #  Second-last item
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to ETHproductions.*

```
∙p»îS2~ª
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f//UcfMgkO7D68LNqo7tOr//2hDHQVTHQUjHQVjMMMSTFrEAgA)

<s>Uh, this is odd but I don't know how else to push a negative number...</s> I don't *really* know Ohm. :P

Comment: Okay, `0 2-` seems very strange...

Comment: Just looking at the docs (I know nothing about Ohm), could you do `2~`?

Comment: @TEHProductions Oh, *much* better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 16 bytes

```
{_,,:)\f{<$-2=}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP2fU/e/Ol5Hx0ozJq3aRkXXyLa29n9dakqs9f9oQwVTBSMFYyBpCcQWsQA)

Returns first element for first.

-2 thanks to [Challenger5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61384/challenger5).

Comment: `{_,,:)\f{<$-2=}}` is two bytes shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 81 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;a=>a.Select((_,i)=>a.Take(++i).OrderBy(n=>n).Skip(i-2).First())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY/fS8MwEMff@1ccPiUsDa4qKLV9cDhRFAcVfBCRmN3kWJtokipj9G@vaYvg8@C4X9x97nvap401tm89mQ@odj5gkyf/K3lP5itPEl0r72GV7BMfVCAN35bW8KDIMB6by9boSzLh5VX8LS5sXaMOZI2XN2jQkZa316Zt0Kn3GofpsoQNFNCrolSywmGcsTdBfKif1BbZbEZcPro1uqsdM0VpuKy29MkozbhckvOBcd5HfYt4xtYonx0FjJqR@eDiG/LORolHAqJtmMEfGFXCfi7gTEAm4GRMLkZ/3nHO84Ng8xE28aKdHkjKRtKxgHQKA3ZCdUnX/wI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

The output array consists of the first element in the input array followed by the desired sequence.

```
£¯YÄ n< g1
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=o69ZxCBuPCBnMQ==&input=WzEsNSwyLDMsNSw5LDUsOF0=)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of array `U`.

```
£
```

Map over `U`, where `Y` is the current index.

```
¯YÄ
```

Slice `U` from `0` to `Y+1`.

```
n<
```

Sort descending.

```
g1
```

Get the second element.

Implicitly output the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
a₀ᶠb{okt}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P/FRU8PDbQuSqvOzS2ofbp3w/3@0oY6pjpGOMZC0BGKL2P9RAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <strike>54</strike> 49 bytes

Thanks to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) -5 bytes. I did not know this feature of `seq()`.

```r
for(i in seq(x<-scan()))cat(sort(x[1:i],T)[2],"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPoTi1UKPCRrc4OTFPQ1NTMzmxRKM4v6hEoyLa0CozVidEM9ooVkdJSfO/IZcplxGXMZC0BGKL/wA)

Comment: `seq(x<-scan())` is shorter by a few bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 123 bytes

```
@set/af=s=%1
@for %%n in (%*)do @call:c %%n
@exit/b
:c
@if %1 gtr %s% set s=%1
@if %1 gtr %f% set/as=f,f=%1
@echo %s%
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

```apl
(2⊃⍒⊃¨⊂)¨1↓,\∘⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/FR2wQNo0ddzY96JwHJQysedTVpHlph@Khtsk7Mo44Zj7oWARUpGCkYKhgoHFoPIg0VjAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Found another 5-byter, *very* different from [Erik's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138521/59487). The arbitrary value is the first element of the list.

```
ηε{Áθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3PZzW6sPN57b8f9/tKGOqY6RjjGQtARii1gA)

---

## Explanation

```
ηε{Áθ  - Full program that reads implicitly from STDIN and outputs to STDOUT.

η      - Push the Prefixes of the list.
 ε     - Apply to each element (each prefix):
  {      - Sort the prefix list.
   Á     - Shift the list to the right by 1, such that the first element goes to the 
           beginning  and the second largest one becomes the last.
    θ    - Get the last element (i.e. the second largest)
         - Print implicitly.
```

---

Let's take an example, to make it easier to understand.

- First we get the implicit input, let's say it's `[1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 9, 5, 8]`.
- Then, we push its prefixes using `η` - `[[1], [1, 5], [1, 5, 2], [1, 5, 2, 3], [1, 5, 2, 3, 5], [1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 9], [1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 9, 5], [1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 9, 5, 8]]`.
- Now, the code maps through the list and sorts each prefix using `{` - `[[1], [1, 5], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 9], [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 9], [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8, 9]]`.
- We then take the very last element and move it to the beginning: `[[1], [5, 1], [5, 1, 2], [5, 1, 2, 3], [5, 1, 2, 3, 5], [9, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5], [9, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5], [9, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8]]`.
- Of course, now the code gets the last element of each sublist using `θ` - `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8]` (the first one being the arbitrary value.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>19</s> 10 bytes

*Thanks to Luis Mendo for shaving off 9 bytes!*

```
"GX@:)SP2)
```

Try it [here](https://matl.suever.net/?code=tn2w2%24%3A%22t%40%3A%29SP2%29w%5Dx&inputs=%5B1%205%202%203%205%209%205%208%5D&version=20.2.2).

#### Explanation

```
"GX@:)SP2)
"                  for all the values in the input
 G                 get input
  X@:)             get values up to the iteration
      SP           sort it in descending order
        2)         get the second value
                   implicit end of loop and output
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Wow! Goes to show how much I know about MATL. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), 13 bytes

```
{x(>x)1}'1_,\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qukLDrkLTsFbdMF4n5n@aup6VuoGVkn5Kapl@cUlKZp7Sf0MFUwUjBWMgaQnEFlyGCoZAPkjEWMGEywjIM1DQBRFAYQA)

```
           ,\ /sublists of increasing lengths (scan concat)
         1_   /remove the first sublist
{      }'     /for each sublist:
  (>x)        /    indices to permute sublist into largest to smallest
      1       /    get second index
 x            /    get sublist[that index]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras`, 41 bytes

```factor
[ head-clump rest [ 1 kth-largest ] map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9NCsIwEEb3PcXnAVq0Vah6AHHjRlyVLkKMbehfTKaglJ49Tqh0hvkgb95i8hKSBusf9@vtckJlh9HovkrUh6xwcOo9ql4qh05QnTgSpB1p6WCsIvoaq3vCOZoicE3Y4YAUGeeRJ8eMDRguKHS@ioEGnmHPGhZxhX8tZbJFHCKs5lVbOo1mX6BW4hnLduwMrHKEgjcN1XErbBXeJR9vUPqQ/APZJP4H)

- `head-clump rest` Prefixes without the first
- `[ 1 kth-largest ] map` Map each to the second-largest element

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```arturo
$->a->map..2size a=>[last chop sort take a&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?YDp6y0)

```
$->a->                  ; a function taking an argument a
    map..2size a => [   ; map over the indices of a sans the first few
        last            ; the last element
        chop            ; of a block without its last element
        sort            ; sorted
        take a &        ; prefix of input given current index
    ]                   ; end map
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 45 bytes

```
Sort[s[[;;i]]][[-2]]~Table~{i,2,Length[s=#]}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/OL@oJLo4OtraOjM2NjY6WtcoNrYuJDEpJ7WuOlPHSMcnNS@9JCO62FY5tlbtf0BRZl6JgkNadLWhjoKpjoKRjoIxmGEJJi1qY/8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>42</s> 39 + 1 (-a) = 40 bytes

```perl
say+(sort{$b-$a}@F[0..$_])[1]for 1..$#F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJbozi/qKRaJUlXJbHWwS3aQE9PJT5WM9owNi2/SMEQyFN2@//fUMFUwUjBGEhaArHFv/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBv91EwE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 3](https://www.swift.org), 67 bytes

```swift
func g(l:[Int]){print((1..<l.count).map{l[0...$0].sorted()[$0-1]})}
```

**[Test Suite.](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/598db322de80147f1a9d2322)**

## [Swift 3](https://www.swift.org), 65 bytes

```swift
{l in(1..<l.count).map{l[0...$0].sorted()[$0-1]}}as([Int])->[Int]
```

**[Test Suite.](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/598db37ede80147f1a9d2323)**

---

#### How to run these?

The first one is a complete function that takes the input as a function parameter and prints the result. You can use them exactly as shown in the testing link. I decided to add instructions though, because the second type of function is used very rarely and most people don't even know of its existence. **Usage:**

```swift
g(l: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4] )
```

The second one is an anonymous function, like lambdas. You can use it exactly as you'd do it Python, declaring a variable `f` and calling it:

```swift
var f = {l in(1..<l.count).map{l[0...$0].sorted()[$0-1]}}as([Int])->[Int]

print(f([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]))
```

**or** wrap it between brackets and call it directly (`(...)(ArrayGoesHere)`):

```swift
print(({l in(1..<l.count).map{l[0...$0].sorted()[$0-1]}}as([Int])->[Int])([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 53 bytes

```php
for(;a&$n=$argv[++$i];rsort($a),print$a[1]._)$a[]=$n;
```

takes input from command line arguments. Output delimited, lead and trailed by semicola.
Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2727b7db12c9c5c48ff7786f6d7a88d4f455340).

Yields a warning in PHP 7.1; replace `a&` with `""<` to fix.
Or use `for(;++$i<$argc;rsort($a),print$a[1]._)$a[]=$argv[$i];` (54 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica 42 Bytes

Independently arrived at a answer very similar to @Jenny_mathy but 3 bytes shorter

```
Sort[#[[;;i]]][[-2]]~Table~{i,2,Length@#}&
```

Realized that the 1st running max takes only 15 bytes and two function calls!:

```
Max~FoldList~#&
```

This can be done so concisely because `Max` has the attributes `Flat` and `OneIdentity` but that's not true for `RankedMax` which would be the logical replacement.  Unfortunately defining attributes or modifying them on existing functions takes up way too many bytes, so the flattening must be done by other means.

All of the nth running maxes can be found in 48 bytes:

```
PadLeft[Sort/@Flatten/@FoldList[{##}&,{},#&@#]]&
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>43</s> 51 bytes

**Edit:** *Added 8 bytes since numerical sorting is desired.*  `:(`

```js
a=>a.map((_,b)=>a.slice(0,b+1).sort((a,b)=>b-a)[1])
```

Keeping this one here, though, as it is shorter providing one wants lexicographical ordering:

```js
a=>a.map((_,b)=>a.slice(0,b+1).sort()[b-1])
```

Both expressions produce `undefined` for the first element.

#### Test code

```js
const golfed =

a=>a.map((_,b)=>a.slice(0,b+1).sort((a,b)=>b-a)[1])

const inputs = [
  [1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 9, 5, 8],
  [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
  [2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2]
];
console.log(inputs.map(x => golfed(x)));
// [ [ undefined, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 8 ],
//   [ undefined, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 ],
//   [ undefined, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 ] ]
```

Comment: Note that I would have preferred to simply comment on the existing JS post if it were not for the reputation system.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I don't like the 50-rep comment threshold either, but I guess they need it to keep spammers from commenting. Anyway, I think this will fail if the input contains a double digit number such as `10`, as `.sort()` sorts lexicographically by default (i.e. 1,10,100,11,12,13,...,2,20,21,...). You'd need to include `(a,b)=>a-b` or similar to get it to sort by number.

Comment: Thanks, @ETHproductions.  I've updated for numerical ordering, which means this is no longer good enough.  Oh, well.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

`FNr2hlQ@_S<QN1`

Try it here: https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=FNr2hlQ%40_S%3CQN1&input=%5B1%2C+5%2C+2%2C+3%2C+5%2C+9%2C+5%2C+8%5D&debug=0

## Explanation

`FNr2hlQ` - For loop with counter 2 <= N <= list length

`@_S<QN1` - 2nd element when the first N elements of the list are sorted in ascending order and then reversed (sorted in descending order)

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 51 bytes

```matlab
@(a){[~,I]=cummax(a);a(I(2:end))=-inf;cummax(a)}{3}
```

- An arbitrary value returned for the first element.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNRszq6Tscz1ja5NDc3sQLIt07U8NQwskrNS9HUtNXNzEuzhkvVVhvX/k/MK9aINlQwVTBSMAaSlkBsEav5HwA)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 56 bytes

```
#(for[i(drop 2(reductions conj[]%))](nth(sort-by - i)1))
```

Maybe there is a better way to generate those prefixes.